# Running Keras LSTM Model In Django Returns 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to integrate my Keras neural network, otherwise working perfectly, into my Django application. When I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get `'thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'`.

Views.py:

```
def index(request):

    form = forms.InputForm()

    args = {'form': form}

    if request.method == "POST":

        print("checking")

        form = forms.InputForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            print(classify(str(form.cleaned_data['textInput'])))

    return render(request, 'main_app/UI.html', args)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class InputForm(forms.Form):
    textInput = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label='Enter text for analysis ')

    def clean(self):
        all_clean_data = super(InputForm, self).clean()
        textInput = all_clean_data['textInput']
```

HTML form code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form method="POST">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Click To Analyse">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I advance?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - I HAVE FOUND A SOLUTION.

The way I resolved the issue was to replace `keras` with `tf.keras`. Then Django accepted the function call.